# Using Google Adsense on Hidden Sections of Domain

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, monetize

I got a verified google Adsense account a few years ago when I was running my own little blog, which related to my web design business. I was able to use the same registered account to set up ads on a music website that I created, under a new dedicated domain.

Now, I'd like to use adsense on my new website, but its a little complicated as the pages are kind of hidden behind a wall.

Let me explain.

My domain is a business and has no need for AdSense on any of the main pages, but I've created a back end section (`---.com/extra/`), where pages that contain adsense banners will be placed.

There is no `index` page on `/extra` as the sites on there are all very differently themed and I generally don't want to go to the hassle of creating the main index page. Most visitors will come via searches and social media.

Any ideas on how I can make sure Google doesn't flag my adverts for technically "hiding" my pages in this manner?

-

**Update** Is it possible that if I create an index.php page containing a list of links to my site (hiding the list with css), google will follow the links and I will not violate any terms?

-

Alternatively, are there any other ways to monetise a site like this without the use of banners? I like the idea of banner placement, but I'm all for trying other methods if they are more suited for my website setup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your content is hiding exactly. It may not be linked from the main site, or in the sitemap, but it sounds like it is visible. There is a good chance it will get indexed by Google anyway.

Even if you were restricting access to the site, let's say to Googlebot, or had it set to noindex, it would still be okay to run AdSense as far as I know. There is a crawler for ads I think that you would need to allow access to.